# My application throws an exception upon execution

Tags: android, fatal-error, runtimeexception

This is my logcat:

> 07-01 17:51:51.190 14519-14519/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   (already on) 07-01 17:51:51.290 14519-14519/? D/AndroidRuntime:
>   Shutting down VM 07-01 17:51:51.290 14519-14519/? E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.exampl.home.assignmentques5, PID: 14519
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.exampl.home.assignmentques5/com.exampl.home.assignmentques5.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                          at com.exampl.home.assignmentques5.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:24)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)  07-01
>   17:52:00.390 14519-14526/com.exampl.home.assignmentques5 W/art:
>   Suspending all threads took: 180ms 07-01 17:56:51.770 14519-14519/?
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14519 SIG: 9

And this is my Java code:

```
package com.exampl.home.assignmentques5;

{
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    Button b1,b2;
    EditText et1,et2,et3,et4,et5,et6,et7;
    TextView tv1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    }
    String s1 = et1.getText().toString();
    String s2 = et2.getText().toString();
    String s3 = et3.getText().toString();
    String s4 = et4.getText().toString();
    String s5 = et5.getText().toString();
    String s6 = et6.getText().toString();
    String s7 = et7.getText().toString();

    int a = Integer.parseInt(s7);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    { 
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button)
        {
            String S = "Your name is "+s1+" "+s2+" "+s3+"\nYour Address is"+et4+" "+et5+" "+et6+" "+a;
            tv1.setText(S);
        }
        else
        {   et1.setText(" ");
            et2.setText(" ");
            et3.setText(" ");
            et4.setText(" ");
            et5.setText(" ");
            et6.setText(" ");
            et7.setText(" ");

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these objects:

```
EditText et1,et2,et3,et4,et5,et6,et7;
```

the are not initialized in the onCreated

so you are trying to get the text of an null referenced **EditText**
before doing this:
(and better move it to inside a method)

```
String s1  ;
String s2  ;
String s3  ;
....
```

init the Wodgets inside the onCreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);


    //
    et1 = (EditText )findViewById(R.id.????);
    et2 = (EditText )findViewById(R.id.????);
    et3 = (EditText )findViewById(R.id.????);
    ...
   initStrings();
}
private void initStrings(){
  s1 = et1.getText().toString();
  s2 = et2.getText().toString();
  s3 = et3.getText().toString();
  s4 = et4.getText().toString();
  s5 = et5.getText().toString();
  s6 = et6.getText().toString();
  s7 = et7.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.exampl.home.assignmentques5, PID: 27772
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.exampl.home.assignmentques5/com.exampl.home.assignmentques5.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: I suggested to move the String init into a method... that is the reason....

Comment: I have updated my answer... take a look now, give a try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to `getText()` on `EditText` that null when class `MainActivity` created. You should initilize your `et1, et2, et3` with `findView` as you doing with buttons in `onCreate` method. And only then you able to `getText()` from them.

Comment: it still gives an exception!

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.exampl.home.assignmentques5, PID: 27772
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.exampl.home.assignmentques5/com.exampl.home.assignmentques5.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference